# Error in building Microsoft's CNTK on Arch Linux: libCntk.Eval-2.0.so complains about undefined reference to TensorView

Tags: undefined-reference, cntk, gcc4.8, gcc7

I am trying to build `CNTK` from the source on `Arch Linux`.

git commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK
cd CNTK
git submodule sync --recursive
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

configure and make commands:

```
./configure --with-mkl=/usr/local/CNTKCustomMKL --1bitsgd=yes --asgd=no
make all
```

The error:

```
building ./bin/cppevalclient for Linux with build type release
/usr/bin/mpic++  -rdynamic -L./lib -L/usr/local/CNTKCustomMKL/3/x64/parallel -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/release/lib -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib' -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/CNTKCustomMKL/3/x64/parallel -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/release/lib -o bin/cppevalclient .build/Source/../Examples/Evaluation/CPPEvalClient/CPPEvalClient.o -lm -lmkl_cntk_p -liomp5 -lpthread -lCntk.Eval-2.0 -lCntk.Math-2.0 -lCntk.PerformanceProfiler-2.0 
./lib/libCntk.Eval-2.0.so: undefined reference to `Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::TensorView<double> const* CNTK::NDArrayView::GetTensorView<double>() const'
./lib/libCntk.Eval-2.0.so: undefined reference to `Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::TensorView<float> const* CNTK::NDArrayView::GetTensorView<float>() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:628: bin/cppevalclient] Error 1
```

`TensorView` is part of `Source/Math`, so I expect `libCntk.Math-2.0.so`. But in the error message, `libCntk.Eval-2.0.so` complains about undefined reference to `TensorView`.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

All three .so files are built and avaiable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 a a 252658744 2017-06-21 21:01 libCntk.Eval-2.0.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 a a 59993400  2017-06-21 21:00 libCntk.Math-2.0.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 a a 1911472   2017-06-21 21:00 libCntk.PerformanceProfiler-2.0.so
```

**Edit 2:**

`mpic++ --version` gives `g++ (GCC) 7.1.1`

The authors suggest to use `gcc 4.8`. However, I would not like to have two versions of `gcc` on the machine.

**Edit 3:**

Based on a suggestion I got from the authors (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2025), I commented out the `EVAL_CLIENT` target in the `Makefile`. However, the error moved to the next target in the `Makefile`: `CNTKLIBRARY_CPP_EVAL_EXAMPLES`

**Edit 4:**

It seems the error is related to the linker and some flags such as `--as-needed`, `--whole-archive`, and so on. However, I could not fix it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it is caused by GCC 7.1.1. If you do not want to install two versions of gcc on the machine, are you able to run docker? CNTK supports docker container too. Details can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/CNTK-Docker-Containers.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Docker containers of CNTK. However, I use Arch Linux as the baseline OS, and I would like to find a solution to compile it with higher versions of GCC to streamline CNTK installation on Arch Linux.